# Ubuntu Chrome "The selected printer is not available or not installed correctly"

Tags: printing, google-chrome

This is on Ubuntu 22.04. Printing had worked fine until now. Suddenly this come up in the Google Chrome Browser selection of any of my printers (except PDF). Printing continues to work fine on firefox, and from other printing apps. I don't want to do a reinstall of chrome, I have many tabs and a lot of configuration and history I don't want to lose.